# Restore original back button behavior

Tags: ios, swift3, navigationitem

In a `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` method I customize icon and behavior of the navigation left button this way:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action, target:self, action:#selector(handleBack))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Is there any way to restore its original appearence and behavior?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: No you can't do that, you have only option to have a custom back image which looks similar to the original, and toggle as you need.

Comment: you mean the ones in the old iOS versions?

Comment: @zombie: as you know, you can change the left button in the navigation bar. I simply asked if, once "overriden" the original button (with its "go back" functionality) it is possible to restore its behavior

Comment: @iphonic: so, if you want to restore the original behavior, all you have to do is redefine its icon and behavior

Comment: @DeyaEldeen: in my current version of iOS (the latest) there are back buttons with arrow, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, but I thought there was some other way

Comment: @IanBell Its good and correct solution. And, i think, its very EZ solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it this way:

In `viewDidLoad` method, add this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action, target:self, action:#selector(handleBack))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

To revert back, do this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

Comment: This is the same thing I wanted to do but I thought there was some other way, that's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

the navigation bar only supports these

[image: buttons]

I gone through extracting iOS assets assets with [this](https://github.com/Marxon13/iOS-Asset-Extractor) and it was so annoying to calibrate the back button to not look fake even though i used the extracted, my advice is let the navigation controller handle this for you by keeping the back that appears when pushing to stack.

Comment: Problem is not always is the case. That is: sometimes, in some viewcontroller, you don't need the back functionality. For example, when a user is logged in, you want to put in that position an icon showing his avatar (when you click that avatar you access a section where the user can edit his profile), etc.